# Impersonating User role in cross-domain

Tags: windows, asp.net-mvc-4, cross-domain, impersonation, httpmodule

In my current application, my testing team is working on a different domain and the production server is on a different domain, where windows authentication is enabled in IIS. The testing team user A (who is a general user) should be able to logon to the server domain with elevated and de-elevated privileges. How can this be done programmatically in ASP.NET MVC 4 C#?
I was planning to create an HTTP Module for impersonation, but the thing is, when application is configured for Windows authentication, IIS will throw out unauthenticated users and it will never reach to the module for impersonation.

Comment: Have you set `<identity impersonate="true" userName="user" password="password" />` in your `system.web` section of your `web.config`? You can also change the current user through code by changing the current `WindowsImpersonationContext`.

Comment: Thank you Cameron, identity impersonation was the only way to achieve it!